# What's failing on the assumptions?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Recall the following version of the Riemann-Lebesgue theorem:

`Theorem:` Let $1 \leq p \leq \infty$, $\Omega = \Pi_1^n(a_i,b_i)$ and $u \in L^p(\Omega)$. Let $u$ be extended by periodicity from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and define $$u_\nu(x) = u(\nu x), \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \bar{u} = \frac{1}{meas \Omega}\int_\Omega u(x)dx,$$then $u_\nu \rightharpoonup  \bar{u}$ in $L^p$ if $1 \leq p < \infty$ and if $p = \infty$, then $\rightharpoonup^* \bar{u}$ in $L^\infty$.

My example is the following: Fix $n = 1$ and let $u(x)=1_{B(0,r)}(x)$ the indicator function of the ball centred at the origin with radius $r > 0$. This function is clearly in $L^2$ with norm $|B(0,r)|^{1/2}$. Define $$u_\nu(x) = u(\nu x) = 1_{B(0,r/\nu)}(x).$$Now, for each $g \in L^2$ it is easy to see that $$\lim_{\nu \rightarrow 0}\int_\Omega u_\nu(x)g(x)dx = \lim_{\nu \rightarrow \infty}\int_{B(0,r/\nu)}g(x)dx = g(0).$$But then $u_\nu \rightharpoonup \delta_0$ where $\delta_0$ is understood as the delta-dirac distribution.

**Question:** What's wrong with this? Why isn't this converging to $\bar{u}$ and where should I have used the function extended by periodicity?

Thanks!

Comment: The limit of the $g$ integral is zero, not $g(0)$. Also in  $\int_\Omega u_\nu g \ne \int_{B(..)}$, here you miss the periodic extension (which period btw)